# Export a Jupyter notebook in AWS SageMaker to HTML file and export it to AWS S3

Tags: html, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I have a Jupyter Notebook setup as following (reproducible):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import boto3
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlparse

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv')

# Data processing
df_aus = df.loc[df['Country/Region']=='Australia'] # filter for Australia
df_aus = df_aus.drop(['Country/Region', 'Lat', 'Long'], axis=1) # remove columns
df_aus = df_aus.transpose() # Transpose
df_aus = df_aus.rename(columns=df_aus.iloc[0]).drop(df_aus.index[0]) # Put the top row as the heading
df_aus.index = pd.to_datetime(df_aus.index) # Convert the index to datetime format
df_aus = df_aus[-365:] # last 365 days of data

ax = df_aus.plot(figsize=(8,6), title='Cumulative COVID-19 Confirmed Cases in Australia by State in the Past Year')
plt.show()
```

I want to convert the Jupyter notebook to HTML file and export it to AWS S3. I am able to export a static picture to S3 now by adding the following code to the above:

```
image_name = 'tmp.png'
plt.savefig(image_name)
s3_uri = 's3://ca-experiment/output/vis/'
url = urlparse(s3_uri)
bucket = url.netloc
key = url.path[1:] + image_name
img_data = open(image_name, 'rb')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket(bucket).put_object(Key=key, Body=img_data, ContentType='image/png')
```

I checked online, and its seems that `nbconvert.HTMLExporter()` should work, then who can provide me with a working example? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easies way is to use the CLI command `jupyter nbconver` (documentation [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)), and then upload the resulting HTML file to S3:

```bash
jupyter nbconvert --to html --execute notebook_name.ipynb --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=conda_python3
aws s3 cp ./notebook_name.html S3://<bucket>/<prefix>
```

The above commands are already pre-installed on SageMaker Notebook instances.

Whereas, below is the Python code to generate HTML output from a notebook execution:

```py
import nbformat
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor
from nbconvert import HTMLExporter

notebook_filename = "notebook_name.ipynb"

with open(notebook_filename) as f:
    nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)

ep = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='conda_python3')

ep.preprocess(nb, {'metadata': {'path': '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/'}})

html_exporter = HTMLExporter()

html_data, resources = html_exporter.from_notebook_node(nb)

with open("notebook_name.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(html_data)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. I put the code below to Lifecycle configuration, the html output is generated in the directory, but it is not uploaded into S3. Could you please help out? Thank you.
```jupyter nbconvert --to html --execute notebook_name.ipynb --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=conda_python3
aws s3 cp ./notebook_name.html S3://<bucket>/<prefix>```